# Sort Hashmap keys by date property of value

Tags: android, kotlin, sortedmap

I have:

```
var schedulesByMonth = HashMap<String, MutableList<Schedule>>()
```

A Schedule has a `startDate: Date` property.

I'm starting with a giant list of `Schedule` objects and sorting them into the hashmap by month.  So if the startDate on the Schedule object is June 2018 it goes into the list for the key `June 2018`.

This is all good but I need the keys for a picker sorted correctly by month:

```
schedulesByMonth.keys
```

if that array is `["July 2018", "August 2018", "June 2018"]` I need it to be `["June 2018", "July 2018", "August 2018"]`.

I know I can make a sortedMap:

```
val sorted = schedulesByMonth.toSortedMap(compareBy<String> {

    }
```

But that only sorts the keys (`String`).  How can I make `it` be the value (`MutableList<Schedule>`) so I can sort by the `startDate` of one of the Schedules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the entries with [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html), which takes a comparator as its argument. Comparators can be created with [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) easily:

```
schedulesByMonth.entries.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.value[0].startDate })
```

Comment: Bingo!  That's brilliant thank you.  I just tagged a `.map { it.key }` to the end and get a nice sorted string array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem here is the wrong key class. Just replace Strings with Dates, and everything will be a lot easier.